# Showing proprietary Ads in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

I have an app and I want to show only my banners inside the app.
I researched for the possibility to show only ads from my company using iAd, but it is not possible.

I was thinking to use a webView to show my banners/ads.

Do you know if Apple will allow this kind of approach?
Have you faced this issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to display whatever advertising you like within your App provided it doesn't breach the content guidelines for the App Store.

There are several third parties that specialize in Ads for iPhone. AdMob allows you to serve 'House Ads' which is what I think you're looking for...

https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619751

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Several apps have this behavior, mostly of them are games. I believe that it isn't a issue to deny your app.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be an issue.  If you are in complete control of them, you don't necessarily even have to use a webView - you can treat them as you would any view within your app.